# How to indent and remove line spacing in HTML unordered list

Tags: android, html

I am using html.fromHtml() method in my android and I want to create a bullet point list:

```
Html.fromHtml("<p><ul><li>30 Cricket Questions</li><font color='#FF0000'><li>400 Seconds</li><li>7 Lives</li></ul></p>");
```

My problem is the line spacing and the indent.

Currently the list is set as so:

```
- 30 Cricket Questions


- 400 Seconds


- 7 Lives
```

I want to close the line space between each item and tab the 7 lives across a bit. How is this done in html? Tried padding=0 but did not work and unsure what the correct command is based on google. Also as a side question, how can I colour a bullet point red and shape it as a square?

Desired output:

```
- 30 Cricket Questions
- 400 Seconds
      - 7 Lives
```

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem and no solution. Have you found a workaround?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use multiples types of [HTML lists](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp).

*Nested lists*

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>
    <font color="red">Item 2</font>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 2.1</li>    
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

*Description lists*

```
<dl>
  <dt>Item 1</dt>
  <dd>description</dd>
  <dt>Item 2</dt>
  <dd>description</dd>
</dl>
```